# Is there a message generator

Tags: delphi

I don’t want to have my messages to the user stored in the application, or in a resource file.

By message I mean, those difficult strings that we have to write to tell the user what is going on or wrong in the application at the precise time.

Is there a simple message generator?

Simple stuff, but as to handle singular/plural and feminine/masculine.

Comment: Will the message generator be stored in the application?

Comment: Why did you create a tag for something that really doesn't exist?

Comment: I don’t want to store the message I want to generate them as needed

Comment: Ok, if it those not exist we need to create it, correct?

Comment: For German at least (and for other languages probably too) the necessary lists of words, the grammar rules and lists of exceptions to those rules combined would be much larger than the messages that the generator solution would replace. There are also languages that have more than just singular and plural forms (dual or trial for example). I don't think a general and multi-language generator is feasible. Simple it won't be anyway.

Comment: Yes. That is my opinion to. So for now it is going to be only for Portuguese. Later I will do it for English.
As for the word list, I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: How was he supposed to know such a thing doesn't exist, @Chris? That's the very purpose of his question, after all. Maybe message generators *do* exist, and this was simply the first question anyone asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There's never an easy solution for this.

Sometimes people use database stored messages, or in some configuration file, that depends on the application.

Comment: That is why I want to generate the messages, and not store them anywhere. 
I have been working in a simple solution. It generates the messages based on simple input, application location, section, etc. 
My problem now is the masculine/feminine and singular/plural. 
May native and output language is Portuguese, but I think it applies to any language. 
I know the rules to form this are very different from language to language. 
So far it works. Reduced my code complexity and clarified it a lot. Also the EXE size reduced dramatically.